# Android: GSM signal strength?

Tags: android, get, set, gsm, signal-strength

I searched the web and i know to get the signal strength. It's working. But what is with "set" the signal strength. Is that possible?

Comment: Set the signal strength? What do you mean? Programatically boosting the signal?

Comment: No, minimize or maximize the signal strength with a progress bar.

Comment: Could you please reword your question? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve one bit.